# Is there a better/cleaner way to format this script

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, shutil, reader

I'm pretty new to python (made 4 scripts to cleanup folders and move some stuff around) and now i have a new challenge.

I have this csv file with data about some pdf's (name of the pdf, times it needs to be printed, etc.)

I have the following code atm and everything works fine, but i find it "unclean" and i hope there was a better way to format some things.
This is my code:

```
import csv, shutil, os

with open('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\OhGreen POS week 19.csv') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    headers = next(rows)

    for row in csvReader:
        NAAM = row[0]
        Formaat = row[1]
        Tekstkleur = row[2]
        Gouvy = row[3]
        LouvainLaNeuve = row[4]
        Nannine = row[5]
        Tournai = row[6]
        SaintGeorges = row[7]
        Aarschot = row[8]
        Balen = row[9]
        Ekeren = row[10]
        Ninove = row[11]
        SintKatelijneWaver = row[12]
        Olen = row[13]
        Zwijndrecht = row[14]

        if Gouvy > "0":
            file = NAAM + ".pdf"
            path = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\" + Formaat + "\\" + file)
            dest = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\2print\\" + Formaat + "\\" + NAAM + "_GOUVY" + ".pdf")
            shutil.copy(path, dest)
            print(dest , " changed name and moved to ", dest)

        if LouvainLaNeuve > "0":
            file = NAAM + ".pdf"
            path = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\" + Formaat + "\\" + file)
            dest = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\2print\\" + Formaat + "\\" + NAAM + "_LOUVAIN_LA_NEUVE" + ".pdf")
            shutil.copy(path, dest)
            print(dest , " changed name and moved to ", dest)

        if Nannine > "0":
            file = NAAM + ".pdf"
            path = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\" + Formaat + "\\" + file)
            dest = ("\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\2print\\" + Formaat + "\\" + NAAM + "_NANNINE" + ".pdf")
            shutil.copy(path, dest)
            print(dest , " changed name and moved to ", dest)
```

This code goes on for every city name in the csv (12 in total)
I want to look for a way to make this cleaner.
Like i don't need to make an if loop for every city and a loop for all the header names etc.

Any tips are welcome.
PS: I won't use Pandas because i can't get it installed properly and it works fine already in basic python

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com. Be sure to read their submission guidelines first, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, store the strings as variables. You seem to be reusing the same string a lot, so if you store it as the variable BASE_PATH, you can do something like this:

```
BASE_PATH = "\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing\\Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\"
path = BASE_PATH + Formaat + "\\" + file
```

or even

```
BASE_PATH = "\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing\\Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\{}\\{}"
path = BASE_PATH.format(Formaat, file)
```

Secondly, you can store the variables you want to check for as a dictionary and loop over its keys. For example:

```py
BASE_PATH = "\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing\\Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\{}\\{}"
DEST_PATH = "\\\\fatboy.leleu.be\\Psm\\Mailing\\Templates\\OhGreen\\Verwerking\\2print\\{}\\{}.pdf"
name_index_mapping = {
  "GOUVY": 3,
  "LOUVAIN_LA_NEUVE": 4,
  "NANNINE": 5
}

for (name, index) in name_index_mapping.items():
  if row[index] > "0":
    file = NAAM + ".pdf"
    path = BASE_PATH.format(Formaat, file)
    dest = DEST_PATH.format(Formaat, NAAM, name)
    shutil.copy(path, dest)
    print(path, "changed name and moved to", dest)
```

Finally, are you sure you need to compare the value to the literal string `"0"` and not the number `0`? Comparing strings using `greater/smaller than` logic can give unexpected results.